# Selenium : driver.get(url) in python loosing context?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm interacting with Twitter through Selenium in Python, and after login, I'm opening "random" urls in Twitter (list of posts).

Each time I do that, brwser shows a "dysconnected" page. I always have to refresh page to get connected and then interact.

Is it a know issue ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import getpass

username = "XXXXX"
login = getpass.getpass("Twitter login :")
password = getpass.getpass("Twitter password :")
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def login_twitter(username, password):
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")

    username_field = driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")
    password_field = driver.find_element_by_name("session[password]")

    username_field.send_keys(username)

    password_field.send_keys(password)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='LoginForm_Login_Button']").click()

# deleting phase
def delete_twitt(twittid):
    base_url = "https://twitter.com/" + username + "/status/"
    twitt_url = base_url + twittid

    driver.get(twitt_url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.refresh()
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='caret']").click()
        del_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Supprimer')]")
        del_button.click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='confirmationSheetConfirm']").click()
    except:
        print(twitt_url)

login_twitter(login, password)
for tweet in json_twitts[300:350]:
    tweet_id = tweet['tweet']['id']
    delete_twitt(tweet_id)
```

Thanks.

Comment: How does the `dysconnected` page looks like? What does the page says?

Comment: As if I was never connected.  Shows twitt and login buttons. (Sorry for disconnected typo)

Comment: Isolating "guilty" part : ```def open_twitt(twittid):
    base_url = "https://twitter.com/" + username + "/status/"
    twitt_url = base_url + twittid

    driver.get(twitt_url)
    driver.refresh()```